# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer in conjunction with animateWithDuration block ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer, animatewithduration

I'm coding an ios application and the basic View is a UIMapView. 
On the UIMapView I have a UIImageView. 
I want this UIImageView's initial state to animate up and down on repeat on the screen. When a user pans across the map I would like the animation to continue. However, when the user stops panning, I would like the animation to stop. The animation should continue whenever the user pans across the screen and stop again when the user stops touching the screen.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I hope u will need this......... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21803627/3800154

Comment: @MayankPatel thank you, this doesn't explain how to get the animation to continue to repeat though